# Was Louis Bloom a meth head in Nightcrawler?

Tags: analysis, character, nightcrawler

I have read the other questions with the 'Nightcrawler' tag and some query the odd behaviour of the film's hero, Louis Bloom.  My question is a bit more direct: was he a meth head?

This suspicion is prompted by his rapid speech, his apparent insomnia, his intense eye contact, and his overall weirdness.

I suppose for the purposes of this question, crack, cocaine, or any class A drug where these symptoms manifest are synonyms so as to prevent me asking: ok, is he a crack head?

Is he a meth head?

Comment: No, his behavior can largely be explained by the medical classification 'sociopath' (AKA psychopath).  Plus he seemed too concerned about money (for me) to think he'd be 'wasting it' on drugs.

Comment: See [this Q&A](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31143/566) which expands on the sociopath angle.

Comment: And also [this related question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/32935/49) about his motivations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know how accurate information are at this website.

> Louis Bloom is a sociopathic, smarmy, but unrelentingly dedicated individual. He will do whatever is necessary to achieve his goals and has no qualms of doing it, justifying his means with the end result.

http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Louis_Bloom

Comment: Thanks, but the wiki does not make a definitive statement about drugs, hence the question here on MSE.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question at all

Answer (score 7):

I just finished watching the film. Unless I'm blanking out on something, nowhere in it did they show Lou taking drugs or even alluded to it. And if it's not in the film, **this remains an unsubstantiated theory.**

You might as well ask if Lou used to be a professional stunt driver in the past because he displayed some impressive maneuvers on the road, or a former debate champion because of his negotiating skills. **This was never shown or discussed, so there's no way for us to know for sure.**

Furthermore, I believe that making him an addict will dilute his character somewhat, as his actions could be blamed on the drugs. *Lou was addicted to power and recognition, and, AFAIK, nothing else.*

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, if the OP is still around. It's not mentioned or explained in the movie or anywhere.